# Centering div box's inside a main div

Tags: css, html, css-float

I am working on a mobile site where the page needs to change based on portrait and landscape mode. I have that part working. When the mobile device is in portrait mode it's suppose to display 4 boxes as such:

[] []
[] []

When in landscape mode, they are to be like this:

[] [] [] []

I have this mostly accomplished, however in both portrait and landscape mode, they are centered left. I have scoured this site and have found similar questions, but when trying to implement the solution, it doesn't seem to work. I would like them to be centered (using percentages instead of fixed width so it shows up correctly on any mobile device). I am not too familiar with CSS, so pardon me, but here is my code below:

```
/* Landscape mode (default) */
div.my_wrapper{
width: auto;
position:relative;
padding:20px;
}

div.my_innerBox {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

div.my_left_box{
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding: 20px;
    /*margin-left:90px;*/

    width: 16%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.my_right_box{
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding:20px;

    width: 16%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.my_header{
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-bottom:12px;
}

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
/* portrait mode */
div.my_wrapper{
width: inherit;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:20px;
}

div.my_innerBox {
    width: 95%;
    display:inline;

}
div.my_left_box{
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    /*margin-left:90px;*/
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.my_right_box{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding:20px 10px;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.my_header{
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
div.my_desc {
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:500px;
}
div.my_header_container {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
}


<div class="my_header_container">
    <div class="my_header">Title Will Go here
        <div class="my_desc">This is where the description content will    go</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my_wrapper">
    <div class="my_left_box">
        Button 1
    </div>

    <div class="my_right_box">
        Button 2
    </div>
    <div class="my_left_box">
        Button 3
    </div>

    <div class="my_right_box">
        Button 4
    </div>

</div>
```

Also, I need where it says "this is where the content description will go" to be to the right of "Title Will Go here", and to be vertically centered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to learn css as I am more of a programmer, not a designer. Thank you, I appreciate any help you can send my way.

Comment: Post this in a jsfiddle so we can have a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tspT4/

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider using a SASS preprocessor and harness the power of numerous Compass extensions.

Here's how your issue is solved with SASS: http://sassbin.com/gist/5785963/

Note how much shorter and easier to read the code is.

@fredsbend said that you can't center something floated. Well, this is not true when SASS automatically sets the widths of all elements precicely to your liking, while you only provide column numbers.

Comment: Crazy how you almost don't even have to code/debug anymore. Won't be long before I just tell my computer what I want it to look like and it does it for me.

Comment: @fredsbend, you're wrong. You still have to code. The difference is that with modern approach you concentrate on the very essence of the problem, rather than waste time building scaffolding and reinventing the wheel over and over again.

Comment: I was exaggerating. I always hard code and I dont perceive that it wastes time. Though I regularly copy and paste from previous projects. I suppose that's no different than using a framework, but I know exactly what the code I'm using is and rarely have to debug.

Comment: Woah, copy-paste is such a magic! It's crazy how you almost don't have to code/debug! Unlike us, the old school programmers who code only by hand and despise modern techniques and methodologies.

Comment: I don't see why you have to be snide.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing the close bracket for the `@media` query.

You cannot expect to center something when a float has been applied to it.

I changed the `float:left;` on the `.my_left_box` and the `.my_right_box` to `text-align:left;` and added `display:inline-block;`. I then added `margin: 0 auto;` and `text-align:center;` to `.my_wrapper` and changed the width to `90%`. I did not make these changes to the `(orientation:portrait)` section.

Here is the css:

```
/* Landscape mode (default) */
div.my_wrapper{
width: 90%;
position:relative;
padding:20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

div.my_innerBox {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

div.my_left_box{
    margin-right:10px;
    padding: 20px;
    /*margin-left:90px;*/
    display:inline-block;
    width: 16%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    text-align:left;
}

div.my_right_box{
    margin-right:10px;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 16%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    text-align:left;
}

div.my_header{
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-bottom:12px;
}

@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
/* portrait mode */
div.my_wrapper{
width: inherit;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding:20px;
}

div.my_innerBox {
    width: 95%;
    display:inline;

}
div.my_left_box{
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    /*margin-left:90px;*/
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.my_right_box{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding:20px 10px;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.my_header{
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-bottom:12px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}

} /* Added here but maybe you want it somewhere else. */

div.my_desc {
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    width:500px;
}
div.my_header_container {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tspT4/10/

---

<sup>I was not able to test this on a mobile but it should work</sup>